# CLion, custom compiler configuration error

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I need to use a Berkeley UPC compiler for my code and I was planning to use it with CLion on Ubuntu 14. Using CMake 3.5.

I set the variable

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/local/berkeley_upc/bin/upcc)
```

on the CMakeLists.txt

but when I reload the CMake project I get the following error:

```
Error:Configuration LBMSolver [Debug]
Compiler exited with error code 2: /usr/local/berkeley_upc/bin/upcc -xc -v -dD -E
upcc: Error: '@/tmp/compiler-arguments.txt' does not exist!
```

This error makes sense as the compiler cant handle some of those arguments.

I was wondering if you could help me with any workaround to this.

Thank you in advance.